# PPP(Cellular) Bonding

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ppp, cellular-internet

I am trying to transfer data over multiple connections.

My system info:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- 2x 100Mbps ETH
- 3x LTE Cellular Modem (Mobile Broadband) connected over USB

I want to use the network interfaces as a load balance. For example:

- ETH0: Connected (27 Mbps)
- ETH1: Connected (24 Mbps)
- BOND0: (51 Mbps)

I can do this with [bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) over ethernet connections. I want to do same thing over Cellular PPP connections.

If you can share keyword to google, a document or link to guide, solution block or any tool, be glad.

Have a solutionly day :D

Answer (score 1):

Bonding (aka [Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)) is not the same as [Network Load Balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing).

- Bonding - use multiple connections as a single connection. ***Data*** is spread evenly over the physical links and reassembled at the remote end.
- Load Balancing - use multiple connections, each existing as an individual with no dependency of the other. ***Connections*** are spread evenly over the physical links. There is no reassembly.

To implement link aggregation over a connection, *both* ends need to be configured to support it. Without support from your Ethernet or cellular service provider, this won't be possible.

---

An alternative that doesn't require support from the "*other end*" is load balancing. This only really provide benefit for the local system (or hosts behind it), for example when accessing the internet - if you are hosting a service, then this will only be beneficial to users if you point them at all of your public IPs (e.g: [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)).

Consider loading a web page - each HTTP request could be sent via a different link to the internet, increasing the perceived bandwidth, and decreasing load times. In practice this can cause issues, so care needs to be taken to configure it correctly.

- Sessions - it's possible that the user will appear to "*jump*" between public IP addresses. Many services will consider this to be a red flag from a security point of view.
- [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) is designed to establish fewer [multiplexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing) connections to a server, rather than the many single-use connections of [HTTP/1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which would reduce the perceived effectiveness of such a configuration.

---

After a bit of searching, I've found a pretty comprehensive write up, which I think is what you're after:

- http://lstein.github.io/Net-ISP-Balance/
- https://github.com/lstein/Net-ISP-Balance

I'm not in a position to test this, and I think it's more complex than an answer here could reasonably explain, hence linking to it.

[image: network diagram]

Comment: Attie thank you for your answer. I was testing Net-ISP-Balance. But the problem does not seem to be resolved. I could not do it with PPP connection. I want to make sure that I'm looking for the right thing. When transferring data on a TCP socket, if 1 link's upload speed is not enough, perform other connections using other connections as well. I can bridge internet in PPP connection to ETH. If I can bridge this to a fake ETH, then bond will be the solution for me. Do you have a suggestion on the idea of fake ETH?

Comment: Unless your service provider supports bonding too, that isn't going to work. I don't know what you mean by "_fake ETH_"...?